# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at AdjMatrixDigraph.main(AdjMatrixDigraph.java:90)

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, indexoutofboundsexception, adjacency-matrix

In my code I am trying to derive an adjacency matrix, but I'm getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at AdjMatrixDigraph.main(AdjMatrixDigraph.java:90)
```

AdjMatrixDigraph.java

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class AdjMatrixDigraph extends StdOut {
    private int V;
    private int E;
    private boolean[][] adj;

    // empty graph with V vertices
    public AdjMatrixDigraph(int V) {
        if (V < 0) throw new RuntimeException("Number of vertices must be nonnegative");
        this.V = V;
        this.E = 0;
        this.adj = new boolean[V][V];
    }

    // random graph with V vertices and E edges
    public AdjMatrixDigraph(int V, int E) {
        this(V);
        if (E < 0) throw new RuntimeException("Number of edges must be nonnegative");
        if (E > V*V) throw new RuntimeException("Too many edges");

        // can be inefficient
        while (this.E != E) {
            int v = (int) (V * Math.random());
            int w = (int) (V * Math.random());
            addEdge(v, w);
        }
    }

    // number of vertices and edges
    public int V() { return V; }
    public int E() { return E; }


    // add directed edge v->w
    public void addEdge(int v, int w) {
        if (!adj[v][w]) E++;
        adj[v][w] = true;
    }

    // return list of neighbors of v
    public Iterable<Integer> adj(int v) {
        return new AdjIterator(v);
    }

    // support iteration over graph vertices
    private class AdjIterator implements Iterator<Integer>, Iterable<Integer> {
        private int v, w = 0;
        AdjIterator(int v) { this.v = v; }

        public Iterator<Integer> iterator() { return this; }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            while (w < V) {
                if (adj[v][w]) return true;
                w++;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public Integer next() {
            if (hasNext()) { return w++;                         }
            else           { throw new NoSuchElementException(); }
        }

        public void remove()  { throw new UnsupportedOperationException();  }
    }


    // string representation of Graph - takes quadratic time
    public String toString() {
        String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.append(V + " " + E + NEWLINE);
        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
            s.append(v + ": ");
            for (int w : adj(v)) {
                s.append(w + " ");
            }
            s.append(NEWLINE);
        }
        return s.toString();
    }


    // test client
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int V = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        int E = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        AdjMatrixDigraph G = new AdjMatrixDigraph(V, E);
        StdOut.println(G);
    }

}
```

StdOut.java

```
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 *  <i>Standard output</i>. This class provides methods for writing strings
 *  and numbers to standard output.
 *  <p>
 *  For additional documentation, see <a href="http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/15inout">Section 1.5</a> of
 *  <i>Introduction to Programming in Java: An Interdisciplinary Approach</i> by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.
 */
public  class StdOut {

    // force Unicode UTF-8 encoding; otherwise it's system dependent
    public static final String charsetName = "UTF-8";

    // assume language = English, country = US for consistency with StdIn
    private static final Locale US_LOCALE = new Locale("en", "US");

    // send output here
    private static PrintWriter out;

    // this is called before invoking any methods
    static {
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, charsetName), true);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }

    // don't instantiate
    public StdOut() { 


    }

    // close the output stream (not required)
   /**
     * Close standard output.
     */
    public static void close() {
        out.close();
    }

   /**
     * Terminate the current line by printing the line separator string.
     */
    public static void println() {
        out.println();
    }

   /**
     * Print an object to standard output and then terminate the line.
     */
    public static void println(Object x) {
        out.println(x);
    }

   /**
     * Print a boolean to standard output and then terminate the line.
     */
    public static void println(boolean x) {
        out.println(x);
    }

   /**
     * Print a char to standard output and then terminate the line.
     */
    public static void println(char x) {
        out.println(x);
    }

   /**
     * Print a double to standard output and then terminate the line.
     */
    public static void println(double x) {
        out.println(x);
    }

   /**
     * Print a float to standard output and then terminate the line.
     */
    public static void println(float x) {
        out.println(x);
    }

   /**
     * Print an int to standard output and then terminate the line.
     */
    public static void println(int x) {
        out.println(x);
    }

   /**
     * Print a long to standard output and then terminate the line.
     */
    public static void println(long x) {
        out.println(x);
    }

   /**
     * Print a short to standard output and then terminate the line.
     */
    public static void println(short x) {
        out.println(x);
    }

   /**
     * Print a byte to standard output and then terminate the line.
     */
    public static void println(byte x) {
        out.println(x);
    }

   /**
     * Flush standard output.
     */
    public static void print() {
        out.flush();
    }

   /**
     * Print an Object to standard output and flush standard output.
     */
    public static void print(Object x) {
        out.print(x);
        out.flush();
    }

   /**
     * Print a boolean to standard output and flush standard output.
     */
    public static void print(boolean x) {
        out.print(x);
        out.flush();
    }

   /**
     * Print a char to standard output and flush standard output.
     */
    public static void print(char x) {
        out.print(x);
        out.flush();
    }

   /**
     * Print a double to standard output and flush standard output.
     */
    public static void print(double x) {
        out.print(x);
        out.flush();
    }

   /**
     * Print a float to standard output and flush standard output.
     */
    public static void print(float x) {
        out.print(x);
        out.flush();
    }

   /**
     * Print an int to standard output and flush standard output.
     */
    public static void print(int x) {
        out.print(x);
        out.flush();
    }

   /**
     * Print a long to standard output and flush standard output.
     */
    public static void print(long x) {
        out.print(x);
        out.flush();
    }

   /**
     * Print a short to standard output and flush standard output.
     */
    public static void print(short x) {
        out.print(x);
        out.flush();
    }

   /**
     * Print a byte to standard output and flush standard output.
     */
    public static void print(byte x) {
        out.print(x);
        out.flush();
    }

   /**
     * Print a formatted string to standard output using the specified
     * format string and arguments, and flush standard output.
     */
    public static void printf(String format, Object... args) {
        out.printf(US_LOCALE, format, args);
        out.flush();
    }

   /**
     * Print a formatted string to standard output using the specified
     * locale, format string, and arguments, and flush standard output.
     */
    public static void printf(Locale locale, String format, Object... args) {
        out.printf(locale, format, args);
        out.flush();
    }

    // This method is just here to test the class
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // write to stdout
        StdOut.println("Test");
        StdOut.println(17);
        StdOut.println(true);
        StdOut.printf("%.6f\n", 1.0/7.0);
    }

}
```

Comment: What a waste of a utility class :-( I know it's not yours, I just disagree with its intended purpose.

Comment: i know its not mine neva said it was am just try to understand to write mine

Comment: I know that. The reason I said I know it's not yours is because I wanted you to understand that I wasn't criticizing *you* for the (IMO) useless `StdOut` class.

Comment: oh ok thanks but i still need help in understanding  it so plss if there is anything you can don about it i would appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 90 is `int V = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);`. Check how you are passing/parsing your command line arguments (the first argument is args[0], the second is args[1], etc.).

Comment: yeaa i  did that before  this was line 90     int V = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);. and it still gave me that same error

Comment: Did you actually pass command line arguments to your program? If you are running it inside an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans, you need to specify the arguments in your options. If you are running it on the command line, you need to do something like `java AdjMatrixDigraph 2 2`.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you to know that the way arrays work is that adj[0] is the first term, adj[1] is the second, adj[2] is the third, so on.  Make sure you aren't calling adj[3] when you mean to say arg[2], this has gotten me in the past.

Comment: i have tried changing it to 0  'int V = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);'

Comment: it still gives me the same error       c:\java>java AdjMatrixDigraph
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at AdjMatrixDigraph.main(AdjMatrixDigraph.java:90)